# General Solution to $\operatorname{Tr} \ln ( I + A)$ where A is complex and symmetric and zero on the diagonal

Tags: matrices, trace

Are there any useful identities which would help me to find a general formula for

$ \operatorname{Tr} \ln ( I + A ) $

Where I is the identity matrix and A is some N by N complex and symmetric matrix, which has zeroes along the diagonal. I have tried splitting A up into upper and lower triangular components and expanding the log with the mercator series but it's starting to get pretty messy already so I think I missed something. Another property of A which could be useful is that it has a special repeating form along the rows and columns:

\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0 & b & c & d & e ..\\
b & 0 & b & c & d.. \\
c & b & 0 & b & c...\\
d & c & b & 0 & b...\\
. & . & . & . & ...\
 \end{array}

It's been a while since I studied matrices so if there is a special name for this I've forgotten!

EDIT: Did a bit of research, this type of matrix is a "Symmetric Toeplitz Matrix".

Comment: The only thing I could think of is an identity $\mathrm{Tr}\ln(1+A)=\ln\mathrm{det}(1+A)$.

Comment: @O.L., your identity becomes problematic of $I+A$ has any negative eigenvalues.

Comment: The go-to reference here is going to be *Functions of Matrices. Theory and Computation* by Nicholas Higham. Fortunately, online sources reproduce some useful pieces of information from this book, because I don't have a copy.

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant: Here there is a conservation of problems in going from the left to the right. One will have the same difficulties when *defining* $\ln (1+A)$.

Comment: That's fair. The logarithm exists if $I+A$ is nonsingular, but to define a unique principal logarithm you need for $I+A$ to have no negative real eigenvalues.